# Building path for Vaadin project

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin6

After Installing Vaadin plugin and downloading Vaadin jars, and configuring the build path. An error is keeping on occur when building the project, something related to `org.jsoup.nodes.Element` but I couldn't figure out why.

> The type org.jsoup.nodes.Element cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: What IDE are you using? And, are you really using Vaadin as your tag suggest, or Vaadin 7? Did you use the plugin to create a simple project or a multi-module project? Also, you should not have to download any Vaadin jars manually; the plugin and Maven do that for you automatically.

Comment: Which Vaadin version do you use?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and I couldn't figure out what was causing it. After trying different ways to solve it, I was suggested to clear the ivy2 cache and resolve again the dependencies by using a different network connection that doesn't involve a proxy. It worked and eventually the jsoup jar was added to the library. Apparently, when downloading the first time the dependencies jars, the jsoup one was blocked by the proxy, and the missing jar in the cache went undetected.

Comment: I too had the same problem with Vaadin 7 (on Eclipse IDE ) and got it solved by cleaning all ivy cache and and resolving the project again. It is caused by jsoup dependency jar not being downloaded properly at the project initialization due to some reason. But clearing ivy cache and resolving again helps.
In eclipse do as follows;
 step 1 : Write click on the vaadin 7 project ---> ivy --> Clean all caches
 step 2 : Write click on the vaadin 7 project ---> ivy --> Resolve

Comment: in case you are using maven, you can delete the jsoup folder in the local repo and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the [jsoup dependency](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.jsoup%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jsoup%22) of vaadin. If you have downloaded the vaadin jars manually the dependencies are missing. It is better to use a build tool like maven or gradle, that automatically takes care of downloading dependencies. Vaadin has a couple of other dependencies which you would all need to download separately if you were just using an IDE.

You can generate a maven or gradle project that is ready to run using [Spring's Initializer](http://start.spring.io/).